# TextView Clickable in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have floating button in the `FundamentalView.axml`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="22dp"
    android:paddingRight="22dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />
   </FrameLayout>
```

In the **FundamentalView.cs**, I have click event which triggers a fragment from the bottom of the view with having options (adding a new person and new calculations).

```
 var addButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.addButton);
 addButton.Click += OnAddButtonClick;

 void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   var dialog = new CardDialogView();
   dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "CardDialogView");        
 }
```

**CardDialogView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_computer"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Calculation"
        local:MvxBind="Click NewCalculationCommand"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_head"
        android:drawablePadding="28dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Person" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is how to make TextView clickable and know which textview clicked in mvvmcross?

**CardDialogView.cs**

```
  public class CardDialogView : MvxDialogFragment<CardDialogViewModel>
  {

       public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
        {
            .....
            return dialog;
        }
  }
```

**CardDialogViewModel.cs**

```
public class CardDialogViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    public ICommand NewCalculationCommand
    {
        get
        {
         // it does not come here!
         return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<NewItemViewModel>(new { date = DateTime.Now }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind textview click just like as button click:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_computer"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        local:MvxBind="Click NewCalculationCommand"
        android:text="New Calculation" />
```

For the second textview bind it to another command. This way when the corresponding command is invoked you will know which textview triggered it.

Comment: Thanks Giorgi, how do I know which textview is clicked?

Comment: Great! Then I need to have `CardDialogViewModel` for the fragment, am I right?

Comment: @hotspring: Yes, you can bind fragment to a viewmodel

Comment: @hotspring: Is there anything in the output window that indicates what's causing the problem ?

Comment: I put a break point in the command, but it did not come there.

Comment: It does not even get into the `CardDialogViewModel`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110578/discussion-between-giorgi-and-hotspring).